# Samba: Error was Permission denied

Tags: samba, centos-5

I've had Samba setup on a Linux CentOS 5.5 server for the past 2 weeks. All of a sudden today it stopped working and I can't figure out why!!

First off I'm running the package "samba3x", version 3.3.8-0.52.el5_5. My configuration file is as follows:

```
[global]
load printers = No
netbios name = MyServer
default = global
path = /home
wins server = 10.1.1.2 # windows pdc
workgroup = workgroup
os level = 20
encrypt passwords = yes
security = share
winbind separator = +
available = No

[In]
writeable = yes
admin users = smbuser
path = /home/myUser/www/share/1
valid users = smbuser
public = yes
available = yes
```

The myUser/, www/ and share/ folders are all set to mode 755 and owned by myUser. The 1/ folder is mode 777 and owned by smbuser.

Windows returns "System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found." when I try to run the command: "net use \MyServer\In /user:smbuser smbuser".

However, if I change the config to use /home/smbuser as the path instead, it works fine! The smbuser/ folder is using 700 and is owned by smbuser. So even though the 1/ folder is using mode 777 and is owned by smbuser, it doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me why please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, just sorted it. Looks like "smbuser" was the problem. Not sure why this should be the case, since the user account was setup correctly and has full access!

I setup an smb account for "myUser" and used that to access the folder instead. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I apologise for not posting as a comment to get some more information - I'm afraid I'm 2 reputation short of being able to do so.

When you've set the `[In]` share to use `path = /home/myUser/www/share/1`, are you then able to run the command `smbclient \\\\127.0.0.1\\In` on your CentOS machine to access that share?

EDIT: Again, I apologise for lack of comments. You probably had conflicting permissions. While the internal folder may have been given full access to a certain user, the parent folders may have *denied* write access (or whatever) to all other users. Deny rules take precedence over allow rules, and this is what I assume happened in your case.

Comment: Hi. I didn't try that, however it turned out to be related to the user account. Thanks anyway though.